# How to Change android app theme in runtime?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm trying to change my app theme during runtime

I've my ChangeTheme class and Utility(SharedPreferences) class

> ChangeTheme.java

```
public class ChangeTheme extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static int THEME_LIGHT = 1;
    private final static int THEME_DARK = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.change_theme_activity);
        updateTheme();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.myoptions,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id){
            case R.id.theme:
                Intent toChangeTheme = new Intent(ChangeTheme.this,ChangeTheme.class);
                startActivity(toChangeTheme);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.lightTheme:
                if (checked){
                    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
                }

                    break;
            case R.id.darkTheme:
                if (checked){
                    setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDark);
                }

                    break;
        }
    }

    public void updateTheme() {
        if (Utility.getTheme(getApplicationContext()) <= THEME_LIGHT) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            }
        } else if (Utility.getTheme(getApplicationContext()) == THEME_DARK) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDark);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSecondary));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

> change_theme_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTheme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change Theme To:"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dp">
    </TextView>

    <RadioGroup
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/lightTheme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Light Theme"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/darkTheme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dark Theme"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

> Utility.java

```
public class Utility {
    public static void setTheme(Context context, int theme) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        prefs.edit().putInt(context.getString(R.string.prefs_theme_key), theme).apply();
    }
    public static int getTheme(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return prefs.getInt(context.getString(R.string.prefs_theme_key), -1);
    }
}
```

> styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppThemeDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorSecondaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorSecondaryAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

When i click in the buttons to change the theme nothing happens, why?
Can you help me?
I've already checked similar questions but nothing've helped

### Update 2020/09/08

> ChangeTheme.java

```
public class ChangeTheme extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static int THEME_LIGHT = 1;
    private final static int THEME_DARK = 2;
    private RadioButton lightThemeButton;
    private RadioButton darkThemeButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.change_theme_activity);

        lightThemeButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.lightTheme);
        darkThemeButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.darkTheme);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.myoptions,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id){
            case R.id.theme:
                Intent toChangeTheme = new Intent(ChangeTheme.this,ChangeTheme.class);
                startActivity(toChangeTheme);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.lightTheme:
                if (checked){
                    Utility.changeToTheme(this, Utility.THEME_LIGHT);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.darkTheme:
                if (checked){
                    Utility.changeToTheme(this, Utility.THEME_DARK);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

> Utility.java

```
public class Utility {

    private static int sTheme;
    public final static int THEME_LIGHT = 0;
    public final static int THEME_DARK = 1;

    //Set the theme of the Activity, and restart it by creating a new Activity of the same type.
    public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme)
    {
        sTheme = theme;
        activity.finish();
        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
    }

    //Set the theme of the activity, according to the configuration. */
    public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity)
    {
        switch (sTheme)
        {
            default:
            case THEME_LIGHT:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
                break;
            case THEME_DARK:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

> styles.xml

```
<color name="color_primary_grey">#212121</color>
<color name="color_primary_black">#000000</color>
<color name="color_accent_white">#aeaeae</color>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="DarkTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary_grey</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent_white</item>
</style>
```

What i've to do now so i can change the theme in runtime?

Answer (score 4):

I did that before for an application of mine.

For my solution I followed the approach presented in [this guide](https://dev.to/emkaydauda/changing-the-color-scheme-at-run-time-for-an-android-app-theme-hack-4i49).

Here are the steps to take:

1. persist the name (or ID) of the theme in the shared preferences. You did that already
2. in the onCreate method of your activity get this string/ID of the theme (defined in the styles) that should be applied like shown below:

```
        // inside activities onCreate method
        // Within your switch command each case should look like this
        theme.applyStyle(R.style.AppColorsDefault, true) // in Java it should be getTheme()
        // for other cases just replace the style
        theme.applyStyle(R.style.AppColorsDark, true) // true forces overwriting attributes that are -potentially - defined by your AppTheme
```

3. Restart your activity in order for your changes to take place (themes can only be set in your onCreate method, thus you need to restart your activity)

```
        val intent = requireActivity().intent // use Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent() in Java
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
        requireActivity().finish() // use getActivity() again
        startActivity(intent)
```

In my solution you also do not need to inherit the theme. The applied style only needs to contain the changes.
Here an example:

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. 
         Also consider using a Material Theme
         Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar
    -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <!-- put all the attributes here that should be applied to the app independent from the applied colors -->
    </style>

    <style name="AppColorsDefault">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>


    <style name="AppColorsDark">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorSecondaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorSecondaryAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

If your application has more than a single activity and you want your changed style(e.g. colors) to be applied to all of them:
Simply create `BaseActivity` that `extends AppCompatActivity` and let all your activities extend this `BaseActivity`

Comment: Ok, i'll try that. Thank u so much

Comment: @أنيسيتوروي How is it going? Did you succeed to implement it already?

Comment: i'm going to implement it now, i had to treat some paperwork in the weekend so it was suspended by now

Comment: I didnt't understood ths line frien:
requireActivity().finish() // use getActivity() again
 I dont have getActivity() method

Comment: Okay then I assume you are not trying to call it from a fragment? Easiest would be to call finish on your main activity. Could you turn your ChangeTheme class into a fragment or eventually a [preference fragment compat](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings#inflate_the_hierarchy)?

Comment: No, i'm not calling from a fragment, but i can do it easily. Then all my activities should extend "ChangeTheme" class, right?

Comment: In my answer look at step 2: call this oncreate method in the activity to apply this style. If you want it to be applied to all activities, then create an empty activity with this onCreate method and let all activities extend it.

Comment: Your ChangeTheme activity does much more than just applying a theme. No need to inherit this theme selection logic to any other activity.

Comment: So, i've added the preference fragment to my change theme activity, but in the documentation you've sended me, idk what is "R.id.settings_container". since any attribute has that id in the documentation.

Comment: can i contact you via skype or something? It's way more easy to talk if u can

Comment: I do not have skype installed and I am only casually passing by at stackoverflow in my free time. I would suggest to post code if it is related to the question. Regarding your `PreferenceFragment` question: it is not related to changing the theme. This fragment should not be started from your ChangeTheme `activity`, it is replacing it. The [android settings library](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/) allows you to easily create a menu-like UI and change values in the `SharedPreferences`. It also offers simple RadioButton menus for selection

Comment: You have deleted all your previous code. Maybe next time just post an update so we can see where you started and how you came to the final solution that solved your problem. Please take a look at your styles vs my suggested styles. Separate the colors from the base theme that inherits from the AppCompat Themes

Comment: Using a preference screen fragment instead of your previous approach using a custom activity was only a suggestion because it will make your task easier in the end. With the preference screen you can also use a ListPreference. You can [find an example here](https://medium.com/@bhavyakaria/step-by-step-guide-to-create-app-settings-using-preferences-in-android-part-2-9dd3466d1e2).

Comment: sorry i didnt'knew i had to update instead of deleting it. I'll watch your example and compare both styles, thank you

Comment: i've updated my question with another method i've thinking of. Can you please check?

Comment: did you delete your previous update again? I see you still didn't separate the colors from your app theme into  a  different style. Also you are using set theme instead of apply style. And you have to call that method from the onCreate method of your activity where you want to apply the style

Comment: Since the new update is way to different from the previous one, i've replaced it so the question don't become to long. What do you mean by separate colors?

Comment: but it is also important to show the whole process of finding the solution. Please compare your styles XML with mine

Comment: Colors should not be in the styles.xml file, is that it?

Comment: either inherit the app theme in both (color) styles or do it the way I did. Remember to upvote an answer that is helping to solve you problem